# efficient array concatenation

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy

Im trying to concatenate several hundred arrays size totaling almost 25GB of data. I am testing on 56 GB machine, but i receive memory error. I reckon the way I do my precess is ineffecient and is sucking lots of memory. This is my code:

```
    for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('/home/extra/AllData'): 
        filenames.sort()
    BigArray=numpy.zeros((1,200))
    for file in filenames:
        newArray[load(filenames[filea])
        BigArray=numpy.concatenate((BigArrat,newArray))
```

any idea, thoughts or solutions?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need a 25Gb array in memory? It will never fit there, you'll need to process it piece by piece.

Comment: @sashkello I do need it in memory as my application runs in realtime.

Comment: The fact that it runs in real time doesn't mean you need all 25Gb all the time. I can be wrong, and maybe you have a very particular case on your hands, but I have a strong feeling that this is a poor program design choice and you need to redo it, rather than trying to fit this huge amount of data. I suggest adding details about your particular situation in your question, otherwise there is really no good answer to it besides "don't do it".

Comment: well its real time image querying. I need that much amount of data in memory to enable fast computation on data points on 25 GB worth of images.

Comment: I think alloc a large array and fill in it is much faster than concatenate, because concatenate will copy the whole array every time.

Comment: As @HYRY suggests, preallocate the array first, although you will need to know the total size first. Problem is that when you do `a = np.concatenate((a, b))`, numpy creates an intermediate array with the concatenation of `a` and `b`, then points variable `a` to it, and if there are no other references to the old `a` it then gets garbage collected. But it requires, even if only for a split second, that you have twice as much memory as the final array.

Comment: Write that up as the answer and claim the coveted checkmark.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your process is *horribly* inefficient. When handling such huge amounts of data, you really need to know your tools.

For your problem, `np.concatenate` is forbidden - it needs at least twice the memory of the inputs. Plus it will copy every bit of data, so it's slow, too.

1. Use [numpy.memmap](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html) to load the arrays. That will use only a few bytes of memory while still being pretty efficient.

   Join them using `np.vstack`. Call this only once (i.e. **don't** `bigArray=vstack(bigArray,newArray)`!!!). Load all the arrays in a list `allArrays` and then call `bigArray = vstack(allArrays)`
2. If that is really too slow, you need to know the size of the array in advance, create an array of this size once and then load the data into the existing array (instead of creating a new one every time).

   Depending on how often the files on disk change, it might be much more efficient to concatenate them with the OS tools to create one huge file and then load that (or use [numpy.memmap](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html))

Comment: I ended up pre allocating the size of the BigArray and inserting the newArrays into it.